# Websphere portal, jboss portlet bridge, jsf, richfaces, facelets - HTTP 500 OK message - issue with a4j modal panel, rich tooltip

Tags: richfaces, facelets, ajax4jsf, jsf-1.2, websphere-portal

We are using the following:
Websphere Portal 6.1.0.2
Websphere App Server 7.0.0.17
Richfaces - 3.3.3
facelets - jsf-facelets-1.1.15
tomahawk12 - 1.1.9
Jboss portlet bridge - 2.1 final

This configuration is mostly working fine on our portal environment and completely works when accessed through app/portal server directly.

When accessed through the IHS web server, all the page comes up but when looked through firebug/httpfox, etc see HTTP 500 OK messages on richfaces and a4j related resources like org.ajax4jsf.javascript.AjaxScript and org.ajax4jsf.javascript.PrototypeScript, org/richfaces/renderkit/html/scripts/jquery/jquery.js and org/richfaces/renderkit/html/scripts/tooltip.js

If I look at the content for those files, it has every bit of data, but just a stamp of 500 OK for the GET request for those resources and the browser is ignoring using those resources. I have tried firefox, IE 7/8, chrome and the modal panel and tooltip does not work and in IE it complaing AFJ undefined, tooltip undefined, etc. I have scoured throuh forums and have tried a lot of suggestions and have not been lucky. Have also tried making the resources available directly, but have not been lucky with that as well.

Like I said earlier, it works just fine when accessing it through Websphere portal server directly. All the components work just fine.

So, wanted to check with knowledgable people on stack overflow if they can shed any light on why I get errors about A4J, Tooltip, ModalPanel undefined when accessing through a web server (eventhough the resources needed looks like is being sent correctly except its been stamped with a 500 OK error message). I can provide any additional details necessary.

Appreciate any help in getting this mystery solved.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with an application running in WAS+IHS but... I think that, the problem is caused by IHS, because without IHS, WAS returned 200 OK.

Maybe you should see this [link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&uid=swg1PM22077) explain something about write a rule for REDIRECT.

Comment: Please don't use URL shorteners when posting links on SO. See this [discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113658/no-url-shorteners) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

We got the issue resolved. The problem was IHS had a setting for ESI - edge side caching enabled through the plugin. After working with IBM, they asked us to set the ESI caching property to false and it started working from web server adn F5 as well.